# LINQ Queries Comparison

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 LINQ Queries here, i just want to know which of these query is proper and fast to use.

Sample I

```
var GetUSer = (from UserItem in dbs.users
               where UserItem.UserID == UserID
               select new User(UserItem))
               .OrderBy(item => item.FirstName)
               .Skip(0)
               .Take(10)
               .ToList();
```

Sample II

```
var GetUSer = (from UserITem in dbs.user
                 .Where(item => item.UserID == UserID)
                 .OrderBy(item => item.FirstName)
                 .Skip(0)
                 .Take(10)
                 .AsEnumerable()
               select new User(UserItem)).ToList();
```

Although they are both working well, i just want to know which is the best.

Comment: Best? In what way exactly? They both look fine to me, but I prefer the second one, looks cleaner. Why not run benchmarks test to determine the speed of which these queries execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Second one  is better,  the first 1 does a select then does filtering,  meaning it has to get the data from the database first to turn it into a User object, then it filters.

The second one will do the query on the DB side, then turn it into a User object

The first one can be fixed by moving the select till just before the ToList()

Comment: Especially if the db isn't local and there are lot of compliant rows, the first one would be much slower

Comment: I dont believe this answer is correct... EF is smart enough not to materialize on the first select in the sequential order of the expressions given

Comment: Just confirmed, EF will generate equal SQL queries for both LINQ queries

Answer (score 0):

Between those two, I would prefer the first (for readability, you'd need to switch some things around if you want the whole query to execute in the database). If they both work, it's up to you though.

Personally, I don't like mixing query syntax with lambda syntax if I don't have to, and I prefer lambda. I would write it something like:

```
var GetUsers = db.user
                 .Where(u => u.UserID == UserID)
                 .OrderBy(u => u.FirstName)
                 .Take(10)
                 .Select(u => new User(u))
                 .ToList();
```

This uses a single syntax, queries as much as possible in the database, and leaves out any superfluous calls.

Comment: Hi. would it effect the performance of your query if your mixing it up  with lambda?